# Maven webapp with non-default web resource directory

Tags: maven

Maven sets the default webapp directory to `src/main/webapp` as per http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html.

We use a IDE-configured server for development, which uses the files from this directory to serve. The server doesn't work from another directory and serves directly from the file system. This has the benefit that every change we make to the source files is visible instantly.

However, all the files in the webapp directory are not minified, not concatenated, etc. I have currently setup grunt to take the files from the webapp directory and put the deployment-ready resources in `src/main/webapp/dist`.

The problem: when building a war, the contents of `src/main/webapp` are copied into the war, but I want **only** the deployment-ready files from `src/main/webapp/dist` to be copied into the war.

I've tried countless google searchs for the topic and I'm feeling stupid. As already stated, I found "http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html", which says "these settings can be overridden via the project descriptor", but it does not show how. I found http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Build_Element which doesn't show the webapp directory. I've found "http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-one-source-directory.html" which again, doesn't specify how to change the directories.

I know I can just specify `src/main/webapp/dist` as an additional resource directory and it will be copied into root war directory. But I don't want all the development files available in the production build.

Also, if someone knows of a better way of handling my general approach, I would like to hear it as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the setting, finally. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html

Add

```
<warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp/dist</warSourceDirectory>
```

to the maven-war-plugin configuration, like so:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp/dist</warSourceDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```